# colaboratory will not acknowledge arviz after installation and import

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3, arviz

In Google's colaboratory, installed arviz then did import arviz without error, but in a code cell, pm.plot_posterior(samples) gets error: arviz not installed.

Trying to plot Bayesian code

```
pm.plot_posterior(samples)
```

I expect a plot

Answer (score 4):

**Install Arviz prior to importing PyMC3**, otherwise it apparently cannot find it. In your case, simply restarting the runtime (**Runtime** > **Restart runtime...**) should get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you try adding the cell magic `%matplotlib inline`? This may be an issue where jupyter-notebook doesn't "know" to render the plot inline