# Error Arviz not installed Using in Google Colab Pymc3

Tags: python, plot, bayesian, pymc3, arviz

I want to plot using pm.traceplot(mcmc_trace,['theta']) in Google Colab but getting error:

ImportError: ArviZ is not installed. In order to use `plot_trace`:

### pip install arviz

NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

Whereas I have already installed Arviz and and import arviz which works but not able to plot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [colaboratory will not acknowledge arviz after installation and import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57733115/colaboratory-will-not-acknowledge-arviz-after-installation-and-import)

Answer (score 0):

Install via pip on Google ColLab will make the plot run of ArviZ again.

```
!pip install pymc3[plots] -q
```