# Google colab has some issues related to the Bayesian analysis and corresponding libraries

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pymc3, arviz

I am studying the book [Bayessian analysis with python](http://93.174.95.29/main/343D1A4DE864D37460EE242DC5B13AFF) and trying to implement all codes in python, for this purpose I use google  colab, but when I am running following code from book

```
import arviz
import pymc3 as pm
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
np.random.seed(123)
n_experiments=4
theta_real =0.35
data =stats.bernoulli.rvs(p=theta_real,size=n_experiments)
with pm.Model()  as our_first_model:
    theta =pm.Beta('theta',alpha=1,beta=1)
    y =pm.Bernoulli('y',p=theta,observed=data)
    start =pm.find_MAP()
    step =pm.Metropolis()
    trace =pm.sample(1000,step=step,start=start)
    burnin=100
    chain =trace[burnin:]
    pm.traceplot(chain,lines={'theta':theta_real})
```

it gives  such errors :

```
AttributeError: Installed version of ArviZ requires PyMC3>=3.8. Please upgrade with `pip install pymc3>=3.8` or `conda install -c conda-forge pymc3>=3.8`
```

before I tried to implement those  libraries

```
!pip install pymc3>=3.8
!pip install arviz
```

but still no success. How do I fix this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [colaboratory will not acknowledge arviz after installation and import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57733115/colaboratory-will-not-acknowledge-arviz-after-installation-and-import)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to restart your session? Once you upgrade using `!pip install pymc3>=3.8`, you will have to restart the session and then do `import pymc3 as pm` otherwise it will still consider the previously installed version.